# Enable preview for video files in finder

Tags: finder, video

There is built-in support for previewing `.mp4` files. However, in the Finder with other video formats such as `.webm`, the icon preview does not work. Is there a a way to achieve this, maybe by some extension?

[image]

Comment: What macOS? webm will show a (still) preview right back to Mojave, but even at Ventura can't play them with Quicklook. Maybe the file just doesn't have an embedded preview. I tested this demo file - [direct download link, SFW] - https://dl6.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm

Comment: Montery. I use VLC for all video, it's set as the default app, but somehow chrome has 'captured' the preview setting. Same result for me with the demo file btw.

Comment: Get Info on a webm file, set Open with: to VLC, then click 'Change All…' - https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LNWe.png [If it's already set to VLC, then idk, sorry]

Comment: The preview is handled by a Quick Look plugin which VLC doesn’t supply.

Comment: @Allan - ah, right. I must have found this long ago, added then forgotten. I use this one - https://github.com/Marginal/QLVideo/wiki

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you so much! This package is a great workaround. Adding this to my repertoire.

Answer (score 0):

### [VLC Media Player](https://www.videolan.org/vlc)

VLC Media Player is an app that supports .webm files, once installed, you should be able to see thumbnails of .webm files directly in Finder.

After having downloaded VLC Media Player by following the on-screen instructions, open it and go to its preferences (press <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>). In the preferences window, make sure you click on "Show All" to see every item there, then, under "Interface", click on "Main Interfaces", and tick "macosx" (no worries, it's also working for macOS).

You should now be able to see .webm file previews in Finder.

Comment: It's not VLC that enables Finder previews, it's Quicklook. I though it was too… but no. See comments above.

Comment: @Tetsujin Oh! Then I guess the only solution would be QLVideo, as you mentioned in your comment.